# sed replace quotation marks

Tags: regex, sed, str-replace

I have the string

```
"Motor des regionalen Neuen Forums"
```

and want to replace the quotation marks to have

```
\q{Motor des regionalen Neuen Forums}
```

gloablly in a file.

How do I do that with sed? Or any other unix tool?
Thanks

Comment: Like `sed 's/"\([^"]\+\)"/\\q{\1}/g' your_file` or `sed -E 's/"([^"]+)"/\\q{\1}/g' your_file`?

Comment: thanks for seeing that I want a general answer.

Comment: If either of them works for you, please let me know so that I could post an answer.

Comment: first one does,  thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following sed command:

```
sed 's/"\([^"]\+\)"/\\q{\1}/g' your_file
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/fV6uW1/1) showing how this regex works. 
In sed, you just need to escape capturing parentheses (`(...)`) and the quantifier `+`. The escape symbol should be doubled to represent a literal `\` 
in the replacement pattern, where a back-reference to the text matched with the first capturing group is used.

Answer (score 0):

> sed -i.BACKUP "s/\"Motor\ des\ regionalen\ Neuen\ Forums\"/\\q{Motor\ des\ regionalen\ Neuen\ Forums}/" yourfile

The .BACKUP part it just creates a backup named yourfile.BACKUP